# Delaying after onDraw()/onCreate()

Tags: android, multithreading, delay, ondraw, oncreate

Where in this code would I put a thread delay, that will happen after the completion of onCreate(), which means also after the completion/showing of onDraw()? Afterwards I will be calling grid.clearPattern() which clears the pattern drawn on the canvas when grid.displayPattern() was called. So afterwards I will still need to be able to modify the canvas.

```
package com.patterns;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class PlayGame extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {
    int size;
    Grid grid;
    PatternView patternview;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    size = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("size");
    patternview = new PatternView(this);
    setContentView(patternview);    

    Handler pauser = new Handler();
    pauser.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            patternview.clearDraw();
        }
    }, 2000);
    patternview.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

public class PatternView extends View { 
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    public PatternView(Context context){
        super(context);


    }

    protected void clearDraw() {
    Log.d("debug", "clearDraw called");
    grid.clearPattern();
}

    @Override 
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        grid = new Grid(size, size, getWidth(), getWidth(), canvas, paint);                     
        grid.createPattern();
        grid.displayPattern();
        Log.d("debug", "lines drawn");
        grid.setBoard();    
        Log.d("debug", "board set");            
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    //Log.d("debug", "screen touched");
    grid.screenTouch(arg1);
    grid.fillActiveRectangles();
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe stick the call to `grid.clearPattern()` into an android.os.Handler?  Had a similar app-pausing problem and this did the trick for me.  So stick something like this at the end of onCreate() -- the 3500 is a pause in milliseconds, choose the value that you want.

```
Handler pauser = new Handler();
pauser.postDelayed (new Runnable() {
public void run() {
        grid.clearPattern();
    }
}, 3500);
```

Comment: The handler thing does exactly what I need the delay to do! But, the call to grid.clearPattern() does nothing. I thought it might be since I didn't call it from a PatternView method, so I changed it to that and still nothing happens. So what do we try next?

Comment: Ok so I've updated the code to what I have now, and after doing some research, it seems the call to clearPattern() does not do anything because A: it is located outside of onDraw() B: it uses the canvas the system created for onDraw() in all of its methods, some of which are outside of onDraw(), eg: clearPattern(). So how do I go about fixing this mess?

Comment: You're starting to wander past what I know (and past the original questions). I  cannot tell what the Grid class is here -- it is not in the android libraries nor in your example. I can tell you that it is kind of odd to have that Grid be declared in the Activity and then have the inner class PatternView referring to it all over the place -- seems like it should be private within the PatternView, and then maybe have a method you call on the PatternView once the pause is complete.  Maybe also call patternview.onDraw() or patternview.invalidate() post-pause.

Comment: Well since I am starting to wander, I will open up a new question. And the grid class is a class I wrote. I will add that code to the new question.

Comment: Sounds good.  Don't forget to mark this answered (if you consider it so).

Comment: Well did a bunch of work today, and I have everything figured out, once the app is done I'll message you and if you want to take a look you can send me your email. Thank you so much for the handler, that was just what I needed. Closing question.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be like this?

```
grid.createPattern();    
grid.displayPattern(canvas, paint); 
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

But it will be a pain...

Comment: I have tried this and it causes a delay, but unfortunately onDraw() is completed before the activity is shown to the user. So they never see the original pattern. Any other ideas? And I don't need to use thread.sleep. As long as it goes original pattern displayed --> delay --> blank grid displayed